# Homework project involving transcription of DNA to mRNA; getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Tags: python

I'm a student in a college "Coding for Beginners" course. Our final project for the class involves creating a DNA sequencer that can print the DNA sequence from user input or a txt file, counting nucleotides in the sequence, transcribing the DNA to mRNA, and translating to polypeptides. I can get the sequence printed and the nucleotides counted, but when it comes to the transcribing, I get this error.

Our class is using Spyder for this project.

This is the code I currently have for transcribing the DNA.

```
def transcribe(DNA):
    mRNA = ""
    for i in DNA:          # Use a for loop to walk through the DNA data
                           # Use an if ... elif ... elif ... elif statement
                           # to do different things depending on which 
                           # nucleotide you find there, add mRNA nucleotides
                           # using the string += "X" function
        if DNA[i] == "C":
            mRNA += "G"
        elif DNA[i] == "A":
            mRNA += "U"
        elif DNA[i] == "T":
            mRNA += "A"
        elif DNA[i] == "G":
            mRNA += "C"
    print ("mRNA sequence: " + mRNA)
    print()
    return(mRNA)
```

After running the program and getting to the point where I can choose to transcribe the DNA to mRNA, this error is received:

```
 if DNA[i] == "C":

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can I fix my syntax to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in DNA:
```

If `DNA` is a string, then `i` will take on the value of each character in that string, not an integer value.

The `if` statement inside the loop can compare `i` directly to the values you're looking for.

```
if i == "C":
    mRNA += "G"
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` will be a character since `DNA` is a string, so you can use a dictionary to translate each letter easily:

```py
def transcribe(DNA):
    mRNA = ""
    translation = {'C' : 'G', 'A' : 'U', 'T' : 'A', 'G' : 'C'}
    for i in DNA:
        mRNA += translation[i]

    print ("mRNA sequence: " + mRNA)
    print()
    return(mRNA)
```